# #sql Count total items by category

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a table ITEMS and table CATEGORY.

table CATEGORY

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  NAME  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | ANIMAL |
|  2 | FRUIT  |
+----+--------+
```

table ITEMS

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| ID |  NAME  | ID_CATEGORY |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | RABBIT |           1 |
|  2 | CAT    |           1 |
|  3 | APPLE  |           2 |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

How to count total items by category? the results is like this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| CATEGORY | TOTAL_ITEMS |
+----------+-------------+
| ANIMAL   |   2         |
| FRUIT    |   1         |
+----------+-------------+
```

the mysql code that I have tried is like this,

```
SELECT CT.NAME,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITEMS WHERE ID_CATEGORY = CT.ID_CATEGORY) AS TOTAL_ITEMS
FROM CATEGORY CT;
```

but failed. the results were not what I wanted. I don't know the algorithm to get results like that.

Comment: Research joins and aggregate functions.

Comment: Failed? What does this mean? Do you get an error? Which? Or wrong results? Which? The query looks fine to me.

Comment: @P.Salmon Ok, i will research and try that now

Comment: There are several solutions (one in answer), but it might be enough to correct the typo in the column name: not " ID_CATEGORY = CT.ID_CATEGORY ", but " ID_CATEGORY = CT.CATEGORY " - as per the two tables you have shown.

Comment: I suppose that you are getting an error because there is no column `CATEGORY` in the `CATEGORY` table. Change `SELECT CT.CATEGORY` to `SELECT ct.name`. And yes, you also got confused with the IDs. When you get an error message when running a query, **read it**. If you don't understand it, **show it to us**.

Comment: `CT.ID_CATEGORY` doesn't exist, so at least one problem seems obvious.

Comment: Why don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Solution#1** : Join and group by

```
SELECT c.name, count(*)
FROM CATEGORY c INNER JOIN ITEMS i on c.ID = i.ID_CATEGORY
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Check this for more detail

**JOIN** : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

**GROUP BY** : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

---

**Solution #2**

```
SELECT CT.NAME, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITEMS 
                 WHERE ID_CATEGORY = CT.ID) AS TOTAL_ITEMS 
FROM CATEGORY CT;
```

The query given in question is also correct but There is syntax error. To get it please compare this SQL query with the SQL you tried.

Comment: w3schools is still supposed a bad ressource. I would not recommend using this as a reference. Here is one of many places in the Internet where people say so (and I agree): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com.